# Accessing a 10GB H2 database file in a Hadoop environment

Tags: java, hadoop, h2, distributed-computing

I have a Java application that will need to connect to a ~10GB H2 database file (read only) In a non-distributed environment, the user would just provide a system file path to the H2 database to the application.

However, when working in a distributed environment, such as Hadoop, what's the best practice for distributing such a large database file to each node?
 Does each node need to have the 10GB database file transferred to it or is there a way to have just a single instance of the database file, say on the master node have all child nodes connected to that single instance instead?